# Is "to kill time" the proper expression to describe slowing down a game?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

In soccer, it is common for players to feign injuries or slow down in order to get to the end of the game without allowing the other team to score. In this context, is the expression

> to kill time

appropriate, or is there a more specific expression? In German, we distinguish between passing the time while waiting for something to start (*Zeit vertreiben*) and actively "wasting" time to hinder an opponent (*Zeit schinden*).

Comment: It might be used, but "stall" or "delay" might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Run down the clock**

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+down+the+clock)  "In sports, to protect a lead by using up as much possible time that remains in a game or match without giving the opposing team a chance to score, generally by maintaining a passive or defensive strategy. With just a narrow two-point lead, the home team is trying to run down the clock to hold out for a win. I don't know, Jim, there's a lot of game time left for them to start running down the clock already."

**Winding down the clock**

**Running out the clock** (and others) [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_out_the_clock)

Answer (score 2):

*To kill time* usually implies dealing with boredom, so you are doing something unimportant because you are waiting for something else to happen, for example

*Whilst he waited on the platform for the train to arrive, he killed time by checking his Facebook account.*

So it is like *vertreiben* not like *schinden*. Your football example is the latter and we would say *waste time*.

Comment: And it sometimes attracts a yellow card for _time wasting_.